# yii2 Active Record что значит "self" ? Для чего он нужен?

Tags: yii2

```
<i>public static function getOne($id)
{
    // получить записи где id=1 и получить одну запись
    $data =self::find()
        //->where(['id'=>1])
        ->where(['id'=>$id])
        ->one();

    return $data;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Извините, это не yii2 Active Record.

Это основы PHP, да и в принципе любого языка программирования. В ActiveRecord он служит для генерирования запроса (ActiveQuery) к конкретной модели из базы данных.
Так сказать для авто подстановки таких значений как `from` и `select` если вы сами их не переопределите.

P.S. Лучше всего откройте класс ActiveRecord и разберитесь, что к чему.

Answer (score 0):

К YII это отношения не имеет. Это конструкция PHP. `self` означает что идет обращение к статичному методу (как в вашем случае) или переменной, которые определенны и реализованы в этом же классе или его родителях.

Т.е. в данном примере вызывается метод `find`, который реализован в том же классе, что и метод `getOne`